# Не корректный вывод sprintf

Tags: perl

Добрый день, подскажите почему sprintf не обрабатывает некоторые числа и ставит вместо них `-000000000001`

```
while ($AllDataRowTND=$dbqueryTND->fetchrow_arrayref()){
my $f11=sprintf("%013d",@$AllDataRowTND[9]);
my $lengthf11=length(@$AllDataRowTND[9]);
print @$AllDataRowTND[9],"     ",$f11,"\n";
}
```

Вывод:

```
    147552          0000000147552
    8861460504     -000000000001
    3579408         0000003579408
    173674665864   -000000000001
    254400         0000000254400
    19506120       0000019506120
    78162218520    -000000000001
    8259096        0000008259096
    4488080280     -000000000001
    2570712        0000002570712
    1565484744     0001565484744
    250584         0000000250584
    427360243248    -000000000001
    742400256        0000742400256
    158498832        0000158498832
    361624992816     -000000000001
    59785272          0000059785272
    314067564936     -000000000001
    486608688         0000486608688
    80281008          0000080281008
    256494442128     -000000000001
```

Comment: Покажите что у вас выведет такой код: `print ~0 >> 1;`. Или такой (в командной строке): `perl -V:[i]vsize`.

Comment: Выводит 2147483647

Comment: Кажется понял, это ограничение 32х битной версии Perl, запуск из под 64 битной решил проблему.

Comment: Ну да. Или, если нужна арифметика с такими числами независимо от архитектуры, можно использовать модуль [Math::Int64](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int64). А может и просто формат `%u` поможет, если речь только о выводе беззнаковых интов, не превышающих 32 бита.

Comment: А с какой целью выводится **срез** массива?

Answer (score 0):

### Perl x64 x32 максимальное и минимальное значение скаляра

---

- 32-bit максимальный и минимальный ints и double floats: 2 в 53 степени = 9007199254740992
- 64-bit максимальный и минимальный ints и double floats: 2 в 64 степени = 18446744073709551615, отрицательное: -2 в 63 степени = 9223372036854775808
- 64-bit максимальный и минимальный ints и quadruple floats: 2 в 113 степени = 10384593717069655257060992658440192

Максимальным значением без использования [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Math-BigInt-1.999811/lib/Math/BigInt.pm) в 32 битной версии будет 9007199254740992

Возможное решение:`my $x = Math::BigInt->new('56789012345678901234');`